# Take top N elements from each group in PySpark RDD (without using groupByKey)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have an RDD like the following

```py
dataSource = sc.parallelize( [("user1", (3, "blue")), ("user1", (4, "black")), ("user2", (5, "white"), ("user2", (3, "black")), ("user2", (6, "red")), ("user1", (1, "red"))] )
```

I want to use `reduceByKey` to find Top 2 colors for each user so the output would be an RDD like:

```py
sc.parallelize([("user1", ["black", "blue"]), ("user2", ["red", "white"])])
```

so I need to reduce by key and then sort each key's values, i.e. (number, color) on number and return top n colors.

I don't want to use `groupBy`. If there is anything better than `reduceByKey` other than `groupBy`, it would be great :)

Answer (score 1):

You can for example use a [heap queue](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/heapq.html). Required imports:

```py
import heapq
from functools import partial
```

Helper functions:

```py
def zero_value(n):
    """Initialize a queue. If n is large
    it could be more efficient to track a number of the elements
    on heap (cnt, heap) and switch between heappush and heappushpop
    if we exceed n. I leave this as an exercise for the reader."""
    return [(float("-inf"), None) for _ in range(n)]

def seq_func(acc, x):
    heapq.heappushpop(acc, x)
    return acc

def merge_func(acc1, acc2, n):
    return heapq.nlargest(n, heapq.merge(acc1, acc2))

def finalize(kvs):
    return [v for (k, v) in kvs if k != float("-inf")]
```

Data:

```py
rdd = sc.parallelize([
    ("user1", (3, "blue")), ("user1", (4, "black")),
    ("user2", (5, "white")), ("user2", (3, "black")),
    ("user2", (6, "red")), ("user1", (1, "red"))])
```

Solution:

```
(rdd
    .aggregateByKey(zero_value(2), seq_func, partial(merge_func, n=2))
    .mapValues(finalize)
    .collect())
```

Result:

```
[('user2', ['red', 'white']), ('user1', ['black', 'blue'])]
```