# Collecting first N entries for each key in KeyVal RDD in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have an RDD with a large number of KeyVal entries. The same key will be present multiple times and I am interested in extracting the first N entries for each key. Being very new to Spark, I have so far been unable to figure out how to do this, so any help would be appreciated.

Input could look like:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([('a',1),('a',2),('b',3),('a',5),('b',4),('b',6)])
```

Desired final output for, say, first 2 entries for each key:

```
output = {'a':[1,2], 'b':[3,4]}
```

If I was only interested in the top n entries in general I could of course just apply `take(n)` to the initial RDD. What I am looking for is a way to something similar to the `take(n)` function, but iterating over each keys. If I can create an RDD that just holds the desired subset of the original RDD, this would be fine. Collecting to a dictionary afterwards is less of an issue.

So intermediate output (RDD-style) would be:

```
[('a',1),('a',2),('b',3),('b',4)]
```

How can I achieve this in PySpark?

Edit: The suggested duplicate question was specifically requiring a solution using `reduceByKey`, which is not a requirement in this case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PYSPARK : use sort with reduceByKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41903310/pyspark-use-sort-with-reducebykey)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listen here child...

```
nLength = 2
rdd.groupByKey().map(lambda x: (x[0], list(x[1])[:nLength]))
```

**Explanation:**

```
rdd.groupByKey()
```

Group the RDD by the key (in our case: 'a' or 'b'). Results in:
*[('a', ResultIterable), ('b', ResultIterable)]*

---

```
.map(lambda x: (x[0], list(x[1])[:nLength]))
```

This parts created a tuple: On the left side, the key ('a' or 'b'), and on the right side we're creating a list from the ResultIterable (x[1]), and then cutting the list from 0 till nLength ([:nLength]).

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something simple as this would do the job:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([('a',1),('a',2),('b',3),('a',5),('b',4),('b',6)])
n = 2
rdd.groupByKey().map(lambda x : (x[0], list(x[1])[:n])).collect()
```

Output:

```
[('b', [3, 4]), ('a', [1, 2])]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 def slice_list(s,no_of_values):
        return s[0:no_of_values]


rdd.groupByKey().map(lambda x: (x[0],slice_list( list(x[1]),2))).collect()
```